# How to align multiple run text in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `TextBlock` with multiple `Run` text as:

```
<TextBlock Name="txtArea" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15" Foreground="#343434">
   <Run FontSize="15pt" Text="Area" Name="lblArea" Foreground="#343434"/><LineBreak/>
   <Run Name="lblAreaValue" FontSize="18pt" Foreground="#343434" Text="{Binding Path=Carpet_area}"/>sq.ft
</TextBlock>
```

I'm trying to align vertically first `Run` block i.e *lblArea* exactly with second block i.e *lblAreaValue* but second run block is slightly moving towards right

Comment: what is your question??

Comment: The above 1st run block i.e Name="lblArea" im trying to align it exactly with second run block i.e Name="lblAreaValue" vertically.but second run block is slightly moving towards right.

Comment: The different font sizes (15pt vs 18pt) aren't going to help here. You are going to have to play with setting the left margin on the 15pt text, though the amount could well depend on the actual text being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question:

The whitespace between `<TextBlock>` and `</TextBlock>` is significant. If you put everything on one line (including the `<TextBlock>` and `</TextBlock>` tags), your text will align as you expect.

A better solution:

Don't use a TextBlock this way. Since you want to position two elements directly below one another use some XAML element that is **meant** for positioning of other elements. In your case, you could use a StackPanel (orientation="Vertical") to position two TextBlocks, one directly under the other. They will align nicely on screen. Additionaly, your XAML can be nicely formatted, because you are using XAML elements the way they are meant to be used.